# Calling class from script generated from CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Not sure what I am doing wrong here but not getting far.

I have created a class using Coffeescript:

```
# CoffeeScript
App=    
        Title:""
        TopMenu:[]
        AddTopMenu:(title,count,icon)->
            Record=
                Title:title
                Icon:icon
                Count:count                                    
                AddSubMenu:(title,icon,count) ->
                    Title:title
                    Icon:icon 
                    Count:count
```

Output:

```
(function() {
  var App;



  App = {
    Title: "",
    TopMenu: [],
    AddTopMenu: function(title, count, icon) {
      var Record;
      return Record = {
        Title: title,
        Icon: icon,
        Count: count,
        AddSubMenu: function(title, icon, count) {
          return {
            Title: title,
            Icon: icon,
            Count: count
          };
        }
      };
    }
  };

}).call(this);
```

The question is, how to call App.Title or App.AddTopMenu?

I have tried the following:

```
<script>
  App.Title="asdasd";
</script>
<script>
var test = new App();
test.Title="asdasd";
</script>
```

Without luck, cannot find App.

Any help would be great.

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the script generated by CoffeeScript is wrapped in a IIFE, anything declared inside it is hidden from the outside scope - this means that you need to be very specific about what you expose.

There are a number of ways you can do this, which basically depend on where your script is going to run. You could assign it to `window` for the browser, or to `module.exports` for node.js, or use something like Require.js to do your dependency management.

Since it looks like you are going to use this in a browser, you probably want to do something like :

```
window.App =    
    Title: ""
    TopMenu: []
    AddTopMenu: (title, count, icon)->
        Record =
            Title: title
            Icon: icon
            Count: count                                    
            AddSubMenu: (title, icon, count) ->
                Title: title
                Icon: icon 
                Count: count
```

which will attach `App` to the `window` object so it can be called from other scripts.

Comment: or you may want to do a separate assignment to window.App when all the  definitions are done: `window.App = App`